# jquery post not passing data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, post

Solved the block to POSTing caused by .htaccess rules (rewrite), as per a previous thread of mine, and now I'm back here again. My php page now fires a perfect POST using html. But I need to POST data through js to remain on the page without redirecting to destination file. So I have some input select fields, and an icon where onclick I call the function go_compute(). This is the function:

```
function go_compute() {
var sel_1 = document.getElementById('select_1').value;
var sel_2 = document.getElementById('select_2').value;
var sel_3 = document.getElementById('select_3').value;
$.post("compute.php",
    {
        select_1: sel_1,
        select_2: sel_2,
        select_3: sel_3
    },
    function(data,status){
        alert("Passing data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
    });
}
```

The destination php file has code like follows:

```
$selection_1 = $_POST["select_1"];
$selection_2 = $_POST["select_2"];
$selection_3 = $_POST["select_3"];
```

But while with html the 3 values are passed, when I use js (jQuery) the variables are loaded in js (the alert says that) but the values do not pass to compute.php. So POST is not working. If I make a check like:

```
if (isset($_POST["select_1"])) {
  $selection_1 = $_POST["select_1"];
} else {
  echo "Problem: not passed post select_1";
}
```

it confirms I have the problem. So, what's the error in my js code? Please feel free to suggest both jQuery or vanilla ajax code. Thank you.

Comment: Why call a second function? You could just add the alert to the first.

Comment: Are you definitely addressing the correct directory with `$.post("compute.php"...`? Sure it's not `$.post("../php/compute.php"...` or something like that?

Comment: Of course here I've simplified the code, but the answer is YES, the url is the correct one, same url yet tested with <form action="url" name="foo" id="foo"> in html, where the post is correctly fired and compute.php receives the values.

Comment: How exactly did you solve the previous problem you are referring to? That was about not having the `.php` extensions in the URL to begin with, and explicitly rewriting any requests that might still have it. And here in your code, you are again using `/compute.php` – why is this not just `/compute` then to begin with? I think you are still making an external redirect, and that’s how you lose your POST data. Use your developers tools, and check what is actually going on in the network panel.

Comment: I have to come back. Made some other checks. Unluckyly the block comes from .htaccess rules. If I disable them, both jQuery and vanilla ajax syntax works and compute.php receive post data. So the problem still is on how to allow js post while internally redirecting foo.php to foo and externally foo to foo.php. Any suggestion?